# Programmatically authenticate user with Keycloak in java

Tags: java, authentication, keycloak

I have been looking through the Keycloak documentation but cannot see how to do this. With Java, I'd like to take a valid userid and password and then generate a token. How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

--EDIT 2018-08-31--

You can use the [Authorization Client Java API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_service_client_api). Once you have created an AuthzClient object, you can pass the username and password to the [AuthzClient#authorization(username, password)](http://static.javadoc.io/org.keycloak/keycloak-authz-client/4.3.0.Final/org/keycloak/authorization/client/AuthzClient.html#authorization-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) or [AuthzClient#obtainAccessToken(username, password)](http://static.javadoc.io/org.keycloak/keycloak-authz-client/4.3.0.Final/org/keycloak/authorization/client/AuthzClient.html#obtainAccessToken--) method to authenticate the user and get the access token (and/or ID token in the first case):

```
// create a new instance based on the configuration defined in keycloak-authz.json
AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create();

// send the authorization request to the server in order to
// obtain an access token granted to the user
AccessTokenResponse response = authzClient.obtainAccessToken("alice", "alice");
```

On a side note, if possible, you'd rather reuse one of the [Keycloak Java Adapters](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#openid-connect-3) to cover more features, such as other authentication methods (the user is typically redirected to Keycloack WUI where you can enforce very flexible authentication and authorization policies).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okay. What I am looking for, is to use the Java API for keycloak to authenticate a user.

Comment: I changed my answer. It should be more relevant to what you need. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for changing your answer. It looks like what I'm looking for. I tried to implement it and I get a runtime exception: could not find any keycloak.json file in classpath. Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: okay, I think I understand what this keycloak.json file is and where it comes from, but now where does it go?

Comment: According to documentation (check the first link in my answer), the keycloak.json must be on your application's classpath.

Comment: okay, solved that problem. but now have another error: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "auth-server-url"  This field comes from my keycloak.json file generated by my keycloak server.

Comment: "auth-server-url" appears in the documentation for keycloak.json file

Comment: Which version of Keycloak Server do you have? And which version of `keycloak-authz-client` library?

Comment: Yes, of course! my versions were mismatched! 4.3 on keycloak server but I was using an earlier keycloak-authz client! Thank you!!

Comment: now it runs without errors. But there is no response from authzClient.obtainAccessToken(id, password);

Comment: Set the log level to DEBUG for the org.keycloak package to get more info about what's going on. Then do you see any HTTP request/reply to/from the Keycloak server?

Comment: Yes, that worked. error message: Client not allowed for direct access grants

Comment: granted direct access and next problem: Invalid user credentials

Comment: another question though, now that I have a valid token, how can I use it to access for instance a service secured by keycloak? I secured a REST service with keycloak, tried to use the token to access the service, but I get a 404

Comment: A couple of ways to validate Keycloak-issued JWT access tokens: 1) Do it in a reverse proxy, e.g. Apache + mod_auth_openidc and forward claims as headers; 2) In a Java app, you can use Keycloak API: https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/52152ed68486c65b50a04fcf7bd9bbde ; 3) do it manually with any JWT library.

Comment: AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create(); is now throwing an exception. Could not obtain configuration from server [https://keycloak.test.online/auth/realms/master/.well-known/uma2-configuration com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "introspection_endpoint"

Comment: version mismatch again

Comment: @user840930 Hi, I'm in the same situation now. I can obtain an  AuthorizationResponse but I get an error when I call a secured service. Did you find out?

Comment: Make sure your version of the keycloak-authz-client library matches your version of the Keycloak server (or at least same major and minor version).